# Multiple voltage sources

Tags: voltage, comparator

Good day,

A simple question to improve my understanding of multiple voltage sources. If I have two potentiometers with the wipers connected both to one input on a lm339 comparator, each voltage source being 2.5, will the input see 2.5v or 5v? Likewise, if one was increased to 5v and the other the same at 2.5v, would it read 5v, 7.5v or an avg? Any explanation would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Schematic would be more than appropriate.

Comment: Depends what "Connected both to lm339" means, there are multiple ways to wire that up. Draw a schematic...

Answer (score 3):

A potentiometer is just two resistors with a central tap, where you can vary the percentage of each.

Your first scenario looks like the left schematic below.
At 50% on each there is 2.5V on the output.

With one at 5V circuit 2 is your setup. Here you have 5V on the output. R7 is shorted out. Same sort of thing would happen if one was at the ground end. It would take priority.

Anywhere in between on both and you need to do the resistor divider math.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Gn3o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you mean some other connection setup, you need to add that to your question as a schematic.

BTW Connecting pots in parallel to the rails like that is a bad idea. If one is at one Vcc end and the other at ground, you will short out the supply. One at an end and the other close to the other will fry the latter pot.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I uploaded a quick diagram from work to hopefully clarify. The sum voltage at 'In' is what the question was in regards to. Again, thank you.

Comment: Now that I had time to read your answer thoroughly, it made perfect sense. Appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A pot connected across a 'stiff' voltage source looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAIXtu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All three of these are equivalent electrically. Real potentiometers have a maximum current you can draw through the wiper. If you connect the "W" from two together you will have a current flowing depending on the pot rotation angle and voltages and pot element resistances. It would be very easy to destroy a pot.

In general if two such voltage sources are connected together and the current is not so high as to damage things they will be at a potential between that of the two sources if they were left open. The lower resistance source will tend to 'win' more than the higher one. As you can see from the above- the value of R4- the source resistance varies with the pot rotation a (0 <= a <= 1), being at a maximum of Re/4 (where Re is the pot element resistance) in the middle of a linear 'B' taper pot and at a minimum of (ideally) 0 at either end.

If you have two sources defined as above with source resistances R4, R4' and voltages V4, V4', the voltage out will be simply:

Vout = (V4/R4+V4'/R4')*(R4||R4')

You can go back and substitute pot values, angles and so on to get the voltage in terms of the original question (you also need the source voltages, and the pot element resistances).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am at work, but uploaded a quick schematic of the idea. The voltage read at 'in' is what the question was about. Much appreciated.

Comment: My answer is fine as-is and thank you for clarifying your question by including the schematic. Vout in my answer corresponds to your Vin. And, as I said, you can destroy pots easily with that circuit.

Comment: I'll take that under advisement. Cheers

Comment: +1 for "It would be very easy to destroy a pot." You can also short out the supply too.